# Why is the current directory in the output rather than the directory of the file?

Tags: cmd

I must be missing something obvious. The current working directory is `C:\src\t\zf`. The `DIR` command should get the .csv files from the parent directory, `C:\src\t`. I was expecting `%~dpnxa` to output the full path to the files. But, it does not. It uses the current working directory path and appends the filename. What am I missing?

```
echo off
cd
C:\src\t\zf
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b "..\*.csv"') do (echo "%~dpnxa")
"C:\src\t\zf\Aliases.csv"
"C:\src\t\zf\c.csv"
"C:\src\t\zf\iplist.csv"
"C:\src\t\zf\my.csv"
"C:\src\t\zf\original.csv"
"C:\src\t\zf\original2.csv"
"C:\src\t\zf\original3.csv"
"C:\src\t\zf\output.csv"
"C:\src\t\zf\rearrange.csv"
"C:\src\t\zf\rearrange-out.csv"
```

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b "..\..\*.csv"') do (echo "%~dpnxa")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is what the `for` replaceable parameter contents refer to:

- In a simple `for` command, the replaceable parameter refers to a file/folder.
- In a `for /f` the replaceable parameter refers to a text line.

And you are in the second case. Your `for /f` is processing text lines. As you are using a `dir /b` you only get the name and extension of the files, without any path that is only included when the `/s` is also used.

As the `for` replaceable parameter only contains a string (the file name, but just a string), any operation trying to obtain a drive or path (`%~dpa`) not present in the string will use the current directory as information source.

You could try with

```
for %%a in ("..\*.csv") do (echo "%~fa")
```